# In the trigger the result of the select is not set

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have some of tables with identical field values which must not be repeated. I decided to make the generation of value when making INSERT. Trigger getting maximum value and add 1. But after `SELECT MAX(account_number) AS last_account_number INTO last_account_number FROM companies;` last_account_number always null, but the value is there and the request outside trigger itself runs smoothly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER    generate_account_number_for_companies
before insert
ON companies FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN
    DECLARE account_number INT;
    DECLARE last_account_number INT;

    SELECT MAX(account_number) AS last_account_number INTO last_account_number FROM companies;

    IF last_account_number is null THEN
        SET New.account_number = 10000000;
    ELSE
        SET New.account_number = last_account_number + 1;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not need the `AS last_account_number` part in your `SELECT ... INTO` statement. Second, do you have data in your `companies` table currently, or is it empty? If it is not empty, try modifying the statement to exclude `NULL` values:

```
SELECT MAX(account_number) INTO last_account_number FROM companies WHERE account_number IS NOT NULL;
```

You could also add a `coalesce` in there to set it to `0` in the event of a `NULL` return.

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(account_number), 0) INTO last_account_number FROM companies WHERE account_number IS NOT NULL;
```

You also are declaring a variable with the same name as your column that you are trying to select, remove the line: `DECLARE account_number INT;` from your trigger.

Comment: I replaced query upon your, but the problem remained. Now always returns 0.

Comment: Do you have data in the table? What do you get when you execute: `select count(1) from companies;`? Also, if the result is > 0 then execute the following: `select count(1) from companies where account_number is not null;` and compare the results.

Comment: `select count(1) from companies;` => 15, `select count(1) from companies where account_number is not null;` => 11

Comment: I also tried `SET last_account_number  = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(account_number), 0) FROM companies WHERE account_number IS NOT NULL);`

Comment: I guess I overlooked this part in your trigger, remove the line that reads: `DECLARE account_number INT;'.